# Seaborn barplot does not show columns side by side

Tags: python, alignment, bar-chart, seaborn, axis-labels

In the plot below, the threshold bars for the same year are not side by side:

[image: SNS barplot]

I would like to have a plot like this below:

[image]

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Year': \['2017','2018','2019','2019','2019','2019','2020','2020'\],
          'Threshold':\[96, 91, 20.59, 47.37, 78.12, 10.00, 15.00 ,91\],
          'Fee' : \["No","No", "20%", "20%", "5%", "20%", "20%", "No"\]})

    palette={"No": "g","20%": "y", "5%": "r"}

    fig,ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.set_size_inches(10,8)

    g = sns.barplot(x=my_df.index, y="Threshold",hue = 'Fee', palette = palette, data=my_df, ci=None)
    g.set(xticklabels=my_df\['Year'\])

    for p in ax.patches: 
        ax.annotate("%.2f" % p.get_height(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2, p.get_height()),
                    ha='center', va='center', fontsize=11, color='black', xytext=(0, 10), 
                    textcoords='offset points',fontweight='bold')][3]][3]
```

Comment: if you use `g = sns.barplot(x='Year', y="Threshold",hue = 'Fee', palette = palette, data=my_df, ci=None)`, this will get you closer to you're desired output. However, you have to keep in mind that seaborn will keep the relative position of each hues, so the bars will be offset from the year if there is only one hue value, and the various values of a given year/hue combination will be aggregated together.

Comment: Yes, that is the point. I don't want aggregated values per year/hue. I would like a plot similar to the second figure displayed above. Is there another way to do this in seaborn or in other data visualization library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are diverging from the kind of plots that seaborn was designed for, you are better off relying on matplotlib directly rather than trying to bend seaborn to your will

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Year': ['2017','2018','2019','2019','2019','2019','2020','2020'],
          'Threshold':[96, 91, 20.59, 47.37, 78.12, 10.00, 15.00 ,91],
          'Fee' : ["No","No", "20%", "20%", "5%", "20%", "20%", "No"]})
palette={"No": "g","20%": "y", "5%": "r"}

temp_df = my_df.sort_values(by=['Year','Fee'])

years = temp_df['Year'].unique()
max_bars = temp_df.groupby('Year').size().max()
width = .8/max_bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i,(year,yearly_df) in enumerate(temp_df.groupby('Year')):
    N_bars = len(yearly_df)
    offsets = np.linspace(0, (N_bars-1)*width, N_bars)
    offsets -= offsets.mean()
    a = ax.bar(i+offsets, yearly_df['Threshold'], width=width, color=yearly_df['Fee'].replace(palette))
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(years)))
ax.set_xticklabels(years)

for p in ax.patches: 
    ax.annotate("%.2f" % p.get_height(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2, p.get_height()),
                    ha='center', va='center', fontsize=11, color='black', xytext=(0, 10), 
                    textcoords='offset points',fontweight='bold')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Diziet Asahi for sharing this new way of plotting my dataframe. This is the solution I wanted.